# How to pass multiple values to servlet using Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets

I have an Html form from that i need to pass values to servlet using jquery and there it will validates the information and returns the result.But when i try to pass the data using jQuery.
The servlet showing that null value received.

```
<div class="ulogin">
<h2>Login</h2>
<div id="error"></div>
        <form action="Login" method="post" id="spsignin">
        <input type="text" name="uname" class="text validate[required]" id="name" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="pass" class="text validate[required]" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="" id="memberlogin"/>
        </form>
</div>
```

My javascript file is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

//Stops the submit request
$("#spsignin").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
});

//checks for the button click event
$("#memberlogin").click(function(e){

        //get the form data and then serialize that
        dataString = $("#spsignin").serialize();
        dataString1 = $("#spsignin").serialize();

        var uname = $("input#name").val();
        var pass = $("input#password").val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Login",
            data:'uname=' +encodeURIComponent(uname) &'pass=' + encodeURIComponent(pass),
            dataType: "json",

            //if received a response from the server
            success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 if(data.success)
                 {
                     $("#error").html("<div><b>success!</b></div>"+data);
                  }
                 //display error message
                 else {
                     $("#error").html("<div><b>Information is Invalid!</b></div>"+data);
                 }
            },

            //If there was no resonse from the server
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                 $("#error").html(jqXHR.responseText);
            },

            //capture the request before it was sent to server
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
                 //disable the button until we get the response
                $('#memberlogin').attr("disabled", true);
            },

            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                //enable the button
                $('#memberlogin').attr("disabled", false);
            }

        });       
 });
});
```

And the servlet is

```
  package skypark;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 /**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
  */
 @WebServlet("/Login")
  public class Login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Boolean success=true;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Login() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static Connection prepareConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    String dcn="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/skypark";
    String usname="system";
    String pass="tiger";
    Class.forName(dcn);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,usname,pass);
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String uname,pass;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

     uname=request.getParameter("uname");
    pass=request.getParameter("pass");
    Boolean suc;
    try {
        suc = check(uname,pass);
            out.println(suc);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    out.flush();
      out.close();
}
   public Boolean check(String uname,String pass) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
   {
 ResultSet rs = null;
 int i=0;
 Connection con=prepareConnection();
 String Query="select uname,email from passmanager where pass=?";
 PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(Query);

  try
  {
    ps.setString(1,pass);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            if (uname.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("uname")) || uname.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("email"))) 
            {
    rs.close();                                                              
            ps.close();                                                            
            ps = null;               con.close();                                                            
         con = null;  
        success=true;
        i=1;
       break;
    }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
      {
      System.out.println(e);
      }

  if(i==0)
  {
      success=false;
  }
return success;

}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doPost(request,response);
}
  }
```

I think error is with jquery. please any one help me to overcome from this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

`data:'uname=' +encodeURIComponent(uname) &'pass=' + encodeURIComponent(pass)`

which should be

`data: 'uname='+encodeURIComponent(uname)+'&'+'pass='+encodeURIComponent(pass)`

note the missing `+` after `encodeURIComponent(uname)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.Now there have another mistake, servlet returned value is not validating properly in jquery. The servlet is returning true. But else portion of if statement was executing please tell me why it is.

Comment: You either need to have your servlet return a JSON object with the property "success" set to true (e.g. `{success: true}`) or you need to change your `if` statement in the jQuery code to check if `data == "true"`. The problem is that `data.success` is `undefined`. The HTTP response (`data`) is merely "true"

Answer (score 0):

I spot one little error on your Ajax script, your ampersand sign is not part of the string:

```
data:'uname=' + encodeURIComponent(uname) &'pass=' + encodeURIComponent(pass),
```

should be

```
data:'uname=' + encodeURIComponent(uname) + '&pass=' + encodeURIComponent(pass),
```

If that doesn't fix it then here's few more things you can check:

- Check you only have one input element with id 'name' on your html
- Check your request went to right servlet on your servlet mapping
- Check you don't have any filters that intercepts and modify / redirect requests

Other than that your code seem fine

Answer (score 0):

well the issue has been cleared already but other than passing the values one by one you can submit the whole form at once ,have a look at this .

```
<script>
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
       $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
       url:'../calling action or servlet',
       type:'post',
       beforeSend:function()
       {
         alert("perform action before making the ajax call like showing spinner image");
       },
       success:function(e){
        alert("data is"+e);
            alert("now do whatever you want with the data");
       }
       });
    });
</script>
```

and you form would be like this

```
<form id="tempForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="" id="" />
<input type="text" name="" id="" />
<input type="file" name="" id="" />
</form>
```

and you can find the plug in [enter link description here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#download)

Comment: Thank you for reply.Now there have another mistake, servlet returned value is not validating properly in jquery. The servlet is returning true. But else portion of if statement was executing please tell me why it is.

Comment: can you please be precise where r u facing the prob , if the servlet returns correctly , means do u have prob in getting the data in your html page inside the jquery function ??

Comment: I'm facing the problem **if(data.success)** in this line of Jquery. i think the problem because, the servlet returning Boolean type value. Please tell me how to resolve this...

Comment: write alert(data) before the if(data.success) line
and see what is coming in to data as response