# How to pass multiple values from java servlet to javascript using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm newbie on developing Java Servlet. Right now, I know how to pass single value from java servlet to javascript, but I can't find the solution on passing multiple values. Please help me to solve my problem. I'm using jquery for ajax to pass the value from jsp file to java servlet file.

The problem of this is that not getting the value of json object from servlet in **ajax.js**

Here is my codes so far:

**index.jsp:**

```
<fieldset>
<legend>JSP Servlet Practice</legend>
<br>
Enter First Number: <input type="text" id="txt1" />
<br>
<br>
Enter Second Number: <input type="text" id="txt2" />
<br>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="opt" value="Add" id="opt">Add
    <input type="radio" name="opt" value="Min" id="opt">Minus
    <input type="radio" name="opt" value="Mult" id="opt">Multiply
    <input type="radio" name="opt" value="Div" id="opt">Divide
</form>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Enter" id="btn">
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClear">
<input type="submit" id="btnReverse" value="Reverse Number">
```

**ajax.js:** (In this part indicates the event of each button.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnReverse").click(function() {
    $.get('getTextFromJSP2', {
        txt1 : $('#txt1').val(), txt2 : $('#txt2').val()
    }, function(json) {
        $('#txt1').text(json.txt11);
    });
});
```

And this is the java servlet file,
**getTextFromJSP2.java:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clsPL pl = new clsPL();
    String txt1 = request.getParameter("txt1");
    String txt2 = request.getParameter("txt2");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("txt11", txt1);
    json.put("txt22", txt2);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477845/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-servlet-using-jquery

Comment: Might help if you describe the problem you're seeing when you try running this code, to save someone from trying to reverse-engineer the problem before describing a solution?

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman question updated. sorry for that. Problem is not getting values inside the jsonobject in ajax.js

Comment: @akhil_mittal sir that link shows how to pass multiple values from javascript to servlet file. The one that I need is the opposite of that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try putting following?

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: Nothing happened sir :(

Comment: It seems you are passing JSON String from servlet. Can you try to parse this string to JSON object. You can use following code:
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
    $('#txt1').text(jsonObj.txt11);

Comment: Still nothing happened sir. Maybe you know the different approach on how to pass multiple values from servlet to javascript. if yes, please tell how to do that :(

Comment: Sir I used session instead of json or whatever and I got it haha Thanks for your help sir.